# How to send http request in protobuf format by locust

Tags: python, stress-testing, locust

I'm new to `locust`, and I know it has a good support for `http` request in `json` format.

We want to perform stress test on a `http api` with `pb` format, but, how to send `http` request in `protobuf` format by `locust` (instead, `jmeter` supports `pb` format).

Is this the same with uploading file?

```
files = {
'image': open('sample.jpg', 'rb'),
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', files=files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the server expects the data to get transfered. If it expects it to be transfered as a multipart file upload you would use the `files` keyword argument (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). However, if I would guess, I would think that it's more likely that the data were to be transfered as raw data in the POST body:

```
self.client.post("/some/url", data=my_protobuf_data)
```